# How do I make a faucet pour instead of spray?

Tags: faucet

I have dual sinks in my master bathroom.  The faucets are identical, but one pours water in a solid thick stream while the other sprays water in a bunch of small streams.  I'd like them both to pour in a solid thick stream.  Is there an easy adjustment I can make?

Comment: Can you provide and label images?

Comment: I will this afternoon when I get back home!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sounds like the screen in the aerator needs to be cleaned out. To clean the screen unscrew the aerator by hand, do not use a tool such as channel locks to do so because you'll mar the surface. This is what you might typically see in an aerator:

[image]

Disassemble the aerator and clean everything, if you can see through each hole in the mesh screen it should usually work like the properly functioning sink. When reassembling make sure the screen sits properly in the aerator body, the bushing shown in the diagram is to create a gap between the mixer and the screen, in most cases if they are directly touching you will not be getting a good stream from your faucet.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 10):

Sounds like one of the faucets is missing an aerator. They are often screwed on where the water exits the faucet.

Comment: missing, or gummed up.

Comment: Agreed with gummed up. You can replace it (cheaply) or soak it in vinegar for a little while (even more cheaply)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at it from another angle, one faucet "pouring" while another "sprays" sounds to me on the surface like you have dual-action faucets. You normally see these for kitchen faucets, but a (possibly self-styled) house-flipper who owned it last may have gotten a deal from a wholesaler and put them in as bathroom faucets. Given the wide variety of styles for both types of sinks it wouldn't look too out of place:

[image] [image] [image]

If this is the case, there should be controls on the faucet that switch between "faucet mode" and "sprayer mode".

If this isn't the case, then most likely the other answers are right and you have some big clogs in the aerator on the "spraying" faucet.