# Aerator Sprays - Is it a missing part?

Tags: sink

My bathroom sink kind of sprays out like this:

[image: Bathroom sink spraying]

Taking the aerator off reveals a nice stream and clean receptacle for the aerator.

[image: Bathroom sink flow without aerator]

I disassembled the aerator and cleaned a number of chunks off of its screens, but this didn't improve things. The parts of the aerator are shown below. I'm nearly positive that I didn't lose any parts: I have two faucets in the bathroom with this same problem, so I'd have had to have lost the same part twice.

[image: Disassembled aerator]

Shown below is an aerator diagram from [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/10647/35435) DIY question.

[image: Aerator schematic]

My aerator, clearly, doesn't have all of these parts.

My question then is this: am I definitely missing parts (maybe a prior owner disassembled the aerator and lost/tossed them) or is there some trick to reassembling my aerator that I got wrong?

A secondary question is: can I buy these parts separate from the rest of the aerator?

Comment: Also: I don't have enough rep to create the `aerator` tag, but it seems as though it may be a useful subclassification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say its pretty obvious that you're missing the "mixer" and "flow restrictor" which are often one piece, or at least attached to each other.

I also agree with your hypothesis that someone took it apart and purposely removed or lost a piece.  Just get a new aerator - it's a common replacement part because people break them or they get clogged with sediment.